# Creating and associating separate GetX Controllers for same screen which is called again and again

Tags: controller, flutter-getx, state-management

I am using GetX as the state management for my flutter application. In GetX, when we navigate to a screen, the bindings are called and the controllers are instantiated.

I have a scenario where I need the bindings to be called whenever the page is called.

Explained in detail

1. Home Screen having Search Icon
2. On tapping the search icon, we are navigated to the search screen
3. Once the search term is entered, results are shown in the search screen
4. On tapping any of the result, we will be navigated to the detailing screen
5. In the detailing screen, we have the option to search again
6. On tapping the search icon, we have to navigate to the search screen

Navigation stack
Home screen -> Search Screen -> Detailing Screen -> Search Screen

Problem here is, since the search screen and its controller is already in the context, the values from the controllers are shown in the last search screen.

I don't want to lose the data which the user typed in the first search screen also.

Please provide some solution to this.

I have tried Get.create to instantiate the controllers. But it is not providing the result which I am expecting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.